# fork multiple child processes to run other programs

Tags: c, exec, fork

I want from parent program (called daemon) to start 5 child processes of test program with args(all 5 in parallel, not to wait to finish).

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){

    //missing irrelevant part where argum is set

    int status,i;
    char cmd[512];
    pid_t process_id = 0;
    for (i=0; i<=5;i++)
    {
        process_id = fork();
        if (process_id < 0)
        {
            printf("fork failed - %d!\n",i);
            continue;
        }
        else if(process_id > 0) {
            printf("process_id of child process %d \n", process_id);
        }
        else
        {
            sprintf(cmd,"./test %s",argum);
            status = system(cmd);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it starts them but when I run ps -aux to see the processes, besides the good ones (like: ./test [args]) there are some duplicates like: sh -c ./test [args]

***How can I get rid of those starting with "sh -c" ?***

Comment: You might like to read about the `exec*()` family of functions ...

Comment: I read that it replaces current process. Will I be able to launch 5 processes from within ?

Comment: If you call it after `fork()` from the child, yes sure. It'll then recplace the just `fork()`ed off process.

Comment: I tried like this: execl("./test", "test", argum, NULL); and it doesn't recognize the arguments

Comment: Which arguments? `argum`? How is `argum` set and as what is it declared?

Comment: multiple arguments in one line ex: -a value -b value -c value ...

Comment: Please continue reading `man 3 exec`. You need to pass each white-space separated option as a single parameter to `execl*()`.

Comment: I read that it's working like that arg1 arg2 arg3 so I tried manually to add them like this: execl("./test", "test", "-a 1", "-b 2", "-c 0", "-d 8"); I don't get errors anymore like arguments missing but the processes don't appear when I run ps -aux. Any idea why ?

Comment: "*... **each white-space separated** option as a **single** parameter ...*": means:  `execl(..."-a", "1", "-b", "2", ...);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `system()` from the child, use a member of the `exec*()` family of functions.

Calling `execXYZ()` from the `fork()`ed off child process replaces the child process by the new process created from what had been passed to the `execXYZ()` call.

Please note that if `execXYZ()` succeeds it does **not** return.

---

Example for executing `/bin/ls -alrt *.c`:

- The `execl*()` members of the family expect each white-space separate command line option as a single parameter.

  ```
  execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-alrt", "*.c", (char*) 0);
  execlp("ls", "ls", "-alrt", "*.c", (char*) 0);
  ```
- The `execv*()` members of the family expect each white-space separate command line option in the way parameters are passed to `main()`:

  ```
  char * const argv[] = {
    "ls",
    "-alrt",
    "*.c",
    NULL,
  }

  execv("/bin/ls", argv);
  execvp("ls", argv);
  ```

The `exec*p()` family members make use of the environment's variable `PATH` to search for the binary to be executed. So for this example (as for the system command `ls`) the path does need to be specified.

---

At test program:

```
#include <unistd.h>  
#include <stdio.h>

/* This should list the current working directory. */

int main(void)
{
  execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-al", "-rt", (char*) 0);
  perror("execl() failed");
  return 0;  
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I really need the arguments to contain spaces like: arg1 = "-a 1"; arg2 = "-b 2" and so on

Comment: @SamReina: If you would call the program along with its options directly fron the command line, how would you call it?

Comment: I tried as you suggested: execl("./test", "-a", "1","-b", "2","-c", "3",... and it doesn't start either :(

Comment: @SamReina: There was a mistake in my example: It shall be `execl("./test", "test", "-a", "1","-b", "2","-c", "3", ..., (char*) 0);`

Comment: I'm stuck. I really like your answer but I don't know how to implement it with fork. I replaced status = system(cmd); with your solution but it doesn't start the program and I tried almost everything passed thru my mind but still no luck

Comment: I tried that too but without the (char*) 0 in the end. with that added it's working. thanks a lot, I just have to figure out how to convert my list of args to something which exec recognize.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to lose sight of the `sh -c` entries is:

```
sprintf(cmd, "exec ./test %s", argum);
```

The `exec` replaces the shell run by `system()` with the command, instead of having the shell hang around until the `./test` process terminates.

The alternative is outlined by [alk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694576/alk) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18699549/15168) — use the `exec*()` family of functions (system calls).

Comment: yes, it doesn't show sh -c anymore but it still shows the parent program name in ps, besides the child one. maybe it's something wrong with my fork code, dunno